# C# winforms looping through a file 4096 kB at a time, and queue HTTPPosts to the internet

Tags: c#, winforms, file-upload, queue, http-post

Thanks for reading, I genuinely appreciate that I am asking a lot of whoever reads this.

I have to cut a physical file into 4096 kB chunks for upload. I can pick them up from the "other end" easy enough and remake them.

I appreciate there is a lot of [information in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583970/need-loop-to-copy-chunks-from-byte-array) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data) but I am struggling how to fit this all together elegantly

The idea is simply to cut files bigger than 4096kB into smaller parcels. To make it worse: if there is a way to synchronously Queue the send of the files without them having to be put on the local disk (i.e. work only in memory) I would really like that..

```
 //Pseudocode:
 Queue queue = new Queue();
 byte[] currentChunk ;
 int i =0;
 while(currentChunk = openFileinChunks(filename, 4194304)) //4096 kB
 {
      HTTPPoster mypost = new HTTPPoster();
      mypost.add(currentChunk);
      //need comparison here - to know when last loop is happening to use different name :-/ for this next bit
      mypost.uploadedName(filename+"."+ i.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
      queue.Enqueue(mypost);
      i++;
 }

 do
 {
    HTTPPoster Post = (HTTPPoster) queue.Dequeue();
    Post.Run();
 } while (queue.Count != 0);

 class HTTPPoster{
     byte[] sendable;
     string tmpname;
     public void add(byte[] toPost)
     {
          sendable = toPost;
     }
     public void uploadedName(string name)
     {
          tmpname = name;
     }
     public void Run()
     {
         //[preferably some condensed reworked code to replace this] **
     }
 }
```

**: [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2009/03/30/1080526.aspx very handy when trying to do something similar.

The approach in that article is relatively straightforward: you set up the web request then write chunks of data to the stream. However, by setting `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` to false, you prevent the request from buffering the whole file in memory.

The problem with your current approach is that it appears to keep everything in memory - this might cause you problems with larger files.

What does the server component of this look like? That will probably dictate the precise method you use to send the file.

**Edit:**

What about this?

```
int bytesRead;
int bufferSize = 4194304;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    int i = 0;

    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        string postFileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath) + "." + i++.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0');

        if (bytesRead < bufferSize)
        {
            postFileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath) + ".terminus";
        }

        PostFileChunk(buffer, bytesRead, postFileName);
    }
}
```

This will read the file in blocks of 4MB, then call the `PostFileChunk` method (your `HTTPPoster` could come in to play here) to send the data to the server.

Keep in mind that when you are writing the chunk to the post in your `Run` method, use the `bytesRead` - because we are reusing the buffer, if the last read is less than `bufferSize`, it will still contain some of the data from the previous read. `bytesRead` will ensure that these characters don't get written.

Comment: the issue is a simple one.. PHP has a post limit of 8M.. so I want to use half that value (just to be easy about it) and send files up as individual posts.. So I am going to use a final destination format of `myfilename.ext.00000000001 4096kB` `myfilename.ext.00000000002 4096kB` all the way to `myfilename.ext.terminus <=4096kB` the beauty of this approach is that I can incron watch for a file ending in .terminus then rebuild it when I see it. What I need to do is cut a file into 4096k chunks and send it.. it's not really a outofmemory issue it's a "that isn't a loop" issue - i.e. no iterator!

Comment: I have looked and that guy is all about having 500Mb in memory at once but still posting the whole lot- that's not what I am about - I am interested in ONLY HTTP POSTING 4096k files and cutting the file into chunks, whether to read it all at once or not or move the filepointer - well that's just common sense

Comment: this guy is closest, (http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html)  but I still can't get it to work - all I really need is to iterate properly though `Hydrophis Spiralis` work

Comment: perfect! I will add the final answer below :-)

Comment: I might have spoke to soon the last .terminus file is exactly 4096 big.. it should not be a "nice round number" I will see if I can fix

Comment: Remember the advice about using `bytesRead` - it sounds like you are writing out the whole byte array in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
void LikeThat(byte[] file)
    {

        var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(file);
        var b=  new byte[4096];
        while (ms.Length > 0)
        {
            ms.Read(b, 0, 4096);
            //now b contains your chunk, just transmit it!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a path, how do you read that /file/ variable in? How do I set up a is set up a MemoryStream from a path?

Comment: You could use FileStream, replacing MemoryStream there http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy.aspx
Length and Read are part of IO.Stream, which both MemoryStream and FileStream inherit.

Comment: `var b=  new byte[4096];` just returns OutOfMemoryException

Comment: there is no loop here this runs and runs and runs until OutOfMemoryException so this solution should `not` be up-voted as it currently stands

Comment: Mistake here is to initialize array inside loop. Corrected my variant.

Answer (score 0):

this works, I have reduced it to 4096 B (not 4096kB) "chunks" but the principle is the same

NB: there is a small amount of object referencing that is my own - a thing I use called the jsonFolder and jsonDomain, which basically holds the username, password and url and file info.. you should be able to follow this logic though.. i will try to make the time to post this to a tutorial (including the PHP serverSide code, and the incron rebuilder)

```
/******
*   the terminus file format is weird
*   basically it goes like this
*       tmp/myfilename.ext.00000000001  4kB
*       tmp/myfilename.ext.00000000002  4kB
*       tmp/myfilename.ext.00000000003  4kB
*       tmp/myfilename.ext.00000000004  4kB
*       tmp/myfilename.ext.terminus     <=4kB
*   this will re-built here to 
*       dir/myfilename.ext              >16kB <20kB
*/


class classActionType_clientPush : classActionType
{
    string relpath = "";
    jsonFolder myFolder;
    jsonDomain myDomain;
    Queue<HTTPPoster> queue = new Queue<HTTPPoster>();

    /// <param name="relativeLocalFilePath">
    /// this "relativeLocalFilePath" refers to path RE: the ~localFolder~ - this class will cut the file and upload it in 4096kB chunks
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="folder">
    /// use this for the folder pathing
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="domain">
    /// this is for the credentials and the url
    /// </param>
    public void setPath(string relativeLocalFilePath, jsonFolder folder, jsonDomain domain)
    {
        string tmppath = folder.localFolder + relativeLocalFilePath;
        if (File.Exists(tmppath))
        {
            relpath = relativeLocalFilePath;
            myFolder = folder;
            myDomain = domain;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("classActionType_clientPull.setPath():tmppath \"" + tmppath + "\" does not already exist");
        }
    }

    public override void action()
    {
        if (relpath == "")
        {
            throw new Exception("classActionType_clientPull.action():relpath cannot be \"\"");
        }
        /***
         * split it into chunks and copy file to server
         */
        try
        {

            int bytesRead;
            int bufferSize = 4096;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            string filePath = myFolder.localFolder + relpath;
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                int i = 0;

                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    string postFileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath) + "." + i++.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0');

                    if (bytesRead < bufferSize)
                    {
                        postFileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath) + ".terminus";
                    }

                    HTTPPoster mypost = new HTTPPoster();
                    mypost.add(buffer);
                    mypost.setBytes(bytesRead);
                    mypost.setDomain(this.myDomain);
                    mypost.uploadedName(postFileName);
                    queue.Enqueue(mypost);

                    Debug.WriteLine("   nof: HTTPPoster.action() loop counter " + i + "");
                }
            }

            do
            {
                HTTPPoster Post = (HTTPPoster)queue.Dequeue();
                Post.Run();
            } while (queue.Count != 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("   nof: HTTPPoster.action() failed\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}

class HTTPPoster
{
    byte[] sendable;
    string filename;
    int bytes;
    jsonDomain myDomain;

    public void add(byte[] b)
    {
        sendable = b;
    }

    public void uploadedName(string p)
    {
        filename = p;
    }

    public void setDomain(jsonDomain domain)
    {
        myDomain = domain;
    }

    public void setBytes(int bytesRead)
    {
        bytes = bytesRead;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            /***
             * this does the actual post (!gulp)
             */ 
            string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

            HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myDomain.url + "/io/clientPush.php");
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            wr.Method = "POST";
            wr.KeepAlive = true;
            wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();

            string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";

            string formitem;
            byte[] formitembytes;
            classHasher hash = new classHasher();

            rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, "username", myDomain.user);
            formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
            rs.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);

            rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, "password", hash.Decrypt(myDomain.password, "saltysaltsalt"));
            formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
            rs.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);

            rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

            string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
            string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "file", filename, "multipart/mixed");
            byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
            rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

             rs.Write(sendable, 0, bytes);

            byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
            rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
            rs.Close();

            WebResponse wresp = null;
            try
            {
                wresp = wr.GetResponse();
                Stream myStream = wresp.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(myStream);
                Debug.WriteLine("   nof: HTTPPoster.Run() all ok \r\n" + myReader.ReadToEnd());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("   nof: HTTPPoster.Run() finished\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                if (wresp != null)
                {
                    wresp.Close();
                    wresp = null;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                wr = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("   nof: HTTPPoster.Run() !ERROR! \r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);               
        }
    }
}
```